# Windows XP extended or clone desktop not working anymore

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I had this issue few days ago for this given configuration:

Dell laptop connected to an external VGA monitor.

**Before:**

I used it for 2 months in extended desktop without problems, often disconnecting the VGA to walk around then plug it back and it would just extend again (or worst case had to disable extended desktop then activate it again).

**Issue:**

Few days ago I unplugged it again,and at the time to reconnect the external monitor, no way for me to extend the view on this monitor. The external monitor is detected (I can activate extended desktop but there will be no signal, and my CCC app will also detect the external monitor). I tried it with a mate laoptop and it works perfectly fine.

I had disable the extended mode, reboot many times, and try all I could in the CCC app or Windows screen settings preferences.

What am I missing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **The external monitor is detected (I can activate extended desktop but there will be no signal)** <-- that is one of the bigger clues in your problem. What If it IS sending out a signal to that port, but it is the wrong res or refresh rate, you can still get a no-signal or out of range signal error. I have one monitor that was so pickey it worked with only a few res numbers.

Comment: In fact the refresh rate and resolution hasn't been changed, I used it for like 3 months smoothly, and tried back all res, nothing could be done to fix the issue. Working on the duplicate of default monitor in my device manager now.