# Reset Windows XP Screen related settings

Tags: windows-xp

After having no clue about this [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/352596/windows-xp-extended-or-clone-desktop-not-working-anymore), I am wondering if it was possible to reset all screen related settings on a windows xp (SP2) ?

The extended desktop feature was working perfectly fine until one day I could not use it anymore. Running a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4330.

Comment: you need all the registry locations for it. or you could back up the registry and just start deleting :-) (its funny but very possible it is well marked in there) A Driver sweeper/cleaner (3dgurus) and tossing out the monitors in device manager, Then reinstalling the driver package, might be enough to reset it without trying to find all the registry locations. Usually a un-install of the ati/amd driver will NOT remove user settings.

Comment: I wasnt sure if you were going to come back to your original question (older) I was thinking that it might be possible that JUST a cleanup of the junk in the device manager alone might help. Do the hidden devices tweak, and get rid of the leftovers.  it would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

(Unsure if this is mentioned in the other question)

One 'neat' trick within XP is to boot into safe mode, delete items from device manager (some unplugged/hidden/'installed but not detected items' - will show up that you don't see in normal mode) and then reboot into normal mode. They'll get redetected and reinstalled if needed.

Very handy for replacing faulty graphics/network cards, changes in monitors, undetected USB devices & faulty USB drives etc.

Comment: Thanks I will try this solution asap. Edit: Indeed even not booting in safe mode I have two "Default Monitor", damn, this begins pretty well !

Comment: Let us know how it goes, goodluck!

Comment: In fact not "Monitors" menu is available in safe mode, which is weird. Anyway even if I remove one of the "duplicate" of default monitor, it will reappear upon restart. I will try updating the video drivers but it was working fine before with my current drivers.

Comment: Remove both and let Windows redetect what is actually there (+active) is the trick :)

Comment: After removing the two default monitors, every time after a refresh of the devices (external screen VGA plugged or not), the same two default monitors appears.I don't know if at the time it was working it was already like this, but this seems weird.

Comment: Aslong as it's working ok i wouldn't worry. The majority of high end graphics cards will support 2 monitors (and have 2 VGA, 1xDVI & 1xVGA or 2xDVI ports), it just seems strange yours is reporting 2 monitors even with only 1 plugged in... What laptop is it?

Comment: Ye, that is weird, but I didn't checked this part when everything was ok (who would !). It is a DELL Vostro 1088.

Comment: Definately has an [external VGA port](http://toplaptop.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/DELL-Vostro-1088-T6670-Terbaru-2011.jpg), couldn't say for sure if there should be 1 or 2 monitors showing in Device Manager... As for the extended desktop feature, check if its part of the Dell software (and reinstall it) or the graphics card (and reinstall that or update it) :)